# Stringer str_replace fails to work with UTF

Tags: r, regex, stringr, hebrew

I have several strings in Hebrew, that I would like to process using regex
Stringer R library (without using sub of gsub) at Rstudio IDE . However even a simple use of `str_replace` yields output which I cannot use.

For example:

This works fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
englishtext <- "FOO!"
str_replace(englishtext,"\\!","")

[1] "FOO"
```

This doesn't:

```
library(tidyverse)
hebrewtext <- "באר!"
str_replace(hebrewtext,"\\!","")

[1] "áàø"
```

As you can see, the function actually removes the `!` in both cases, yet after this transformation the Hebrew case is unreadable. can I encode it back to Hebrew? even better can I do something that would prevent the problem from appearing?

***** things I tried *****
(1)
the usual script:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Hebrew")
```

doesn't change the result

(2)
thanks to @Wiktor:

```
res <- gsub("!", "", `Encoding<-`(hebrewtext, "UTF8"))
```

this does work! however this is only a solution to the simple case of replacing values in strings while I wish to use all the functionality of Stringr and not gsub.

(3) A friend said that reinstalling Stringr worked for him:

```
install.packages("stringr")
```

but it doesn't work for me

***** session info *****:

> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255
>   LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] saridr_0.1.0       RColorBrewer_1.1-2
>   scales_1.0.0       MASS_7.3-51.1      officer_0.3.4       [6]
>   forcats_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.3        purrr_0.3.2
>   readr_1.3.1        [11] tidyr_0.8.3        tibble_2.1.3
>   ggplot2_3.2.0      tidyverse_1.2.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] tidyselect_0.2.5
>   mitools_2.4      splines_3.5.2    haven_2.1.0      lattice_0.20-38
>   [6] vctrs_0.2.0      colorspace_1.4-1 generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.3.6
>   base64enc_0.1-3  [11] utf8_1.1.4       survival_2.43-3  rlang_0.4.0
>   pillar_1.4.2     glue_1.3.1       [16] withr_2.1.2      DBI_1.0.0
>   uuid_0.1-2       modelr_0.1.4     readxl_1.3.0     [21] relaimpo_2.2-3
>   munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0     cellranger_1.1.0 zip_2.0.2
>   [26] rvest_0.3.2      labeling_0.3     fansi_0.4.0      broom_0.5.1
>   Rcpp_1.0.1       [31] corpcor_1.6.9    backports_1.1.4  jsonlite_1.6
>   hms_0.4.2        digest_0.6.20    [36] stringi_1.4.3    survey_3.36
>   grid_3.5.2       cli_1.1.0        tools_3.5.2      [41] magrittr_1.5
>   lazyeval_0.2.2   zeallot_0.1.0    crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.2 
>   [46] Matrix_1.2-15    xml2_1.2.0       lubridate_1.7.4 
>   assertthat_0.2.1 httr_1.4.0       [51] rstudioapi_0.9.0 R6_2.4.0
>   boot_1.3-20      nlme_3.1-137     compiler_3.5.2

Comment: I have `[1] "באר"` as output. Also [in Linux](https://ideone.com/MvIHOY).

Comment: Try `res <- str_replace(hebrewtext,"!","")` and then `Encoding(res) <- "UTF-8"`

Comment: sadly I don't and using the magic of Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Hebrew") also makes no difference.  It is possible I need to paste my session info for further aid, do you know how can it be done?

Comment: `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Are you sure it is a real issue and not a display issue? Is it in RGui, or RStudio?

Comment: res <- str_replace(hebrewtext,"\\!","") 

Encoding(res) <- "UTF-8"

res

res is the same

Comment: "Are you sure it is a real issue and not a display issue? Is it in RGui, or RStudio?"-  I use Rstudio and I find the problem persisting into ggplot titles and causing all sorts of troubles down the pipe

Comment: Ok, another try with Encoding, try ``gsub("!", "", `Encoding<-`(hebrewtext, "UTF8"))``. Actually, on my Windows machine, this generates some gibberish.

Comment: Use double backticks for code in comments containing `\``. It is just  a problem with how the UTF8 text is displayed in your R environment.

Comment: ``gsub("!", "", `Encoding<-`(hebrewtext, "UTF8"))``
[1] "באר"

`Encoding<-`(hebrewtext, "UTF8") 
[1] "באר!"

this works! but why is it written so?